# VBA IF loop overwrites the result

Tags: vba, loops

I'm new to Macro and I'm trying to create a code which will replace the value of a cell from numbers to Age bracket. If the number in a cell is 7 then it will change to "<12 hours", 26 then should be replaced to "24-36 hours" and so on, "Error" if none meets the criteria. The problem is whenever I re-run the macro, it will loop again and change the previous result to Else value which is "Error". How can I prevent this from happening? Below is my sample code.

```
Sub Ticket_Age()

'Declare variable for Ticket Age
'Dim rCell As Range
Dim age_lastrow As Long, y As Long
Dim age_sheet As Worksheet


Set age_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
age_lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Set rCell = age_sheet.Range("A2:A" & age_lastrow)

    For y = 2 To age_lastrow
        On Error Resume Next
       
        If age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value <= 12 And age_sheet.Range("A" & y) > -5 Then
        age_sheet.Range("A" & y) = "<12 hours"
        If age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value = "<12 hours" Then age_sheet.Range("A" & y) = "<12 hours"
        ElseIf age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value > 12 And age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value <= 24 Then
        age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value = "12-24 hours"
        ElseIf age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value > 24 And age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value <= 36 Then
        age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value = "24-36 hours"
        ElseIf age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value > 36 And age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value <= 48 Then
        age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value = "36-48 hours"
        ElseIf age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value > 48 And age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value < 100 Then
        age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value = "48+ hours"
        Else
        age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value = "Error"
       
        End If

    Next y

End Sub
```

**UPDATE: Finally found a solution to my code. Thanks to suggestion. I added another criteria in my IF condition. It will change if the cell only contains "Numeric" otherwise it will not update the cell.**

```
Sub Ticket_Age()

Dim age_lastrow As Long, y As Long
Dim age_sheet As Worksheet


Set age_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
age_lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    
        For y = 2 To age_lastrow
            On Error Resume Next
            
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value) = True And age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value <= 12 And age_sheet.Range("A" & y) > -5 Then
        age_sheet.Range("A" & y) = "<12 hours"
        
        ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value) = True And age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value > 12 And age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value <= 24 Then
        age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value = "12-24 hours"
        
        ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value) = True And age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value > 24 And age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value <= 36 Then
        age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value = "24-36 hours"
        
        ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value) = True And age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value > 36 And age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value <= 48 Then
        age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value = "36-48 hours"
        
        ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value) = True And age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value > 48 And age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value < 1000 Then
        age_sheet.Range("A" & y).Value = "48+ hours"

        End If

    Next y


End Sub
```

Comment: this is because Excel sees text as greater than any number, so it is greater than 100.  You will need to test if it is text and skip it.

Comment: That woul be the best solution to skip the loop if the cell contains text but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly, you are replacing the numerical value with a string, then, on the second go-round, those strings are giving you error values?
Off the top of my head, I would say create separate columns for "Hours"(numerical) and "Age Bracket" (string), so you can  keep the hours unchanged. You have to store the hours somewhere, if you want to re-use them.

Comment: Right. But I found a solution. Thanks!